# Even though I used Safe area, container 1 doesn't have offset from the bottom of the screen which looks even worse in phones with curved edges

Tags: flutter, dart

This is how it look like even though I use Safe Area:
[image]

```
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
            children:[
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text("Container 1"),
              ),
```

// container 1
],
),// column
), //safe area
),  //scaffold
);   //Material App
}
}

Answer (score 1):

SafeArea is made to avoid intrusions by the operating system(by default). The bottom curve is not considered as intrusion by OS so, it won't solve your purpose.
What you can do int order to attain what you want by adding minimum padding to safearea:

```
home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
    body: SafeArea(
      minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0), //Change value according to your need 
      child: Column(
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
        children:[
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Text("Container 1"),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have not specified constraints of Safe Area try this :

```
home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        body: SafeArea(
          top :true,
          bottom :true,
          left :true,
          right:true,
          child: Column(
            verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
            children:[
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text("Container 1"),
              ),
```